# Call a UI controller with FedAuth cookie from SAML token

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, saml-2.0, adfs, ws-federation

We're trying to automate some integrated tests. So we'd like to be able to programatically call the UI controllers in order to be as clause as what the reel users do. We don't want to use a UI test suite for different reasons.

Problem is that we are using SSO Windows authentication with the WS-Federation security with WIF. In configuration, we use passiveRedirectEnabled="true" so that every time the session cookie is absent, invalid or expired, the page gets redirected to the AD FS STS endpoint ("/adfs/ls/"). The result is again redirected back to page specify in the "reply" attribute in the Web.config file.

When I look in Fiddler, I clearly see the second redirect (coming back from the AD FS STS) with a 302 status returns a "Set-Cookie : FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwg..." instruction to the browser. The the call is made to the reply page with the FedAuth cookie and everything is OK from there.

Is there a way to emulate this behavior and be able to call the UI controller with the correct FedAuth cookie ? No SharePoint please, this has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to reproduce the steps from what I saw in Fiddler to mimic the browser. I'll let the code here, hoping it can help some of you along the way. It's not very clean, it's more in a POC mode but it still can help. Note that on some requests I had to allow the automatic redirection an some others I had to prevent it.

Credits to my colleague Dominique Pothier who helped me a lot on that one.

```
//First request to the secured site
        var request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mysite.mycompany.ca/");
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

//Redirects to the STS based on the response from the first call, posting the ws-federations infos along
        request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(httpResponse.Headers["Location"]);

        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Host = "sts.mycompany.ca";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        request.UserAgent =
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

        var nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection { { "Cache-Control", "max-age=0" } };
        request.Headers.Add(nameValueCollection);
        nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection { { "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1" } };
        request.Headers.Add(nameValueCollection);
        nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection { { "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch" } };
        request.Headers.Add(nameValueCollection);
        nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection { { "Accept-Language", "fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" } };
        request.Headers.Add(nameValueCollection);

        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


//Parse the response to get ws-federation infos
        var responseStream = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        var responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd();
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(responseData));


        var wa = "";
        var wresult = "";
        var wctx = "";

        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.GetAttribute("name") == "wa")
                wa = xmlReader.GetAttribute("value");
            if (xmlReader.GetAttribute("name") == "wresult")
                wresult = xmlReader.GetAttribute("value");
            if (xmlReader.GetAttribute("name") == "wctx")
                wctx = xmlReader.GetAttribute("value");
        }

        httpResponse.Close();

//Redirects to the controller method we want to hit
        request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mysite.mycompany.ca/Home/GetStates");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        //Add the cookie container to the response so that we can get the FedAuth cookie after the response
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        //Add the ws-federation infos from the last http request to the body of the new request
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            if (wa != null)
            {
                var waEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(wa);
                var wresultEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(wresult);
                var wctxEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(wctx);
                var urlEncoded = "wa=" + waEncoded + "&wresult=" + wresultEncoded + "&wctx=" + wctxEncoded;

                streamWriter.Write(urlEncoded);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }
        }
        request.Referer = httpResponse.ResponseUri.OriginalString;

        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var cookieContainer = request.CookieContainer;

//Use the FedAuth cookie that we got from last http call and add it to a new request to the controller and voila !
        request =
            (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mysite.mycompany.ca/Home/GetStates");
        request.Method = "GET";
        nameValueCollection = new NameValueCollection { { "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" } };
        request.Headers.Add(nameValueCollection);
        //Add the FedAuthCookie from last request
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        request.Referer = "https://proacces-dev1.universitas.ca/";

        httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        responseStream = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
        responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine(responseData);
        Console.ReadLine();
```